# Date validation with ASP.NET validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm trying to use an ASP.NET `RangeValidator` to validate a date on a textbox. The format of the date entered on the textbox is `dd MMMM yyyy`.

How can I use the range validator to validate a valid date? If I enter **1 January 1000** as the min or max value I get an error saying value cannot be converted to type date, but if I use another format it picks up my entered text as invalid.

Below is my code:

```
<asp:TextBox 
    runat="server" 
    ID="txtDatecompleted" 
/>
<cc2:CalendarExtender
    ID="datecompletedExtender" 
    runat="server"
    TargetControlID="txtDatecompleted"
    Format="dd MMMM yyyy"
/>  
<asp:RangeValidator 
    runat="server" 
    ID="RangeValidator1" 
    Type="Date" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted" 
    MaximumValue="9999/12/28" 
    MinimumValue="1000/12/28" 
    ErrorMessage="enter valid date" 
    Display="None"
/>
<cc2:ValidatorCalloutExtender 
    ID="RangeValidator1_ValidatorCalloutExtender" 
    runat="server"
    Enabled="True"
    TargetControlID="RangeValidator1">
</cc2:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate the format? because I'm not understanding your problem?

Answer (score 138):

Best option would be

Add a compare validator to the web form. Set its controlToValidate. Set its Type property to Date. Set its operator property to DataTypeCheck eg:

```
<asp:CompareValidator
    id="dateValidator" runat="server" 
    Type="Date"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date.">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Plus the built in controls also check for valid/invalid leap year dates. 2/29/2011 says invalid but 2/29/2012 comes back valid. No need to hassle with fancy regular expressions!

Comment: @Ryan Sammut I also want to know the answer to this question. The Date type CompareValidator accepts MM/DD/YY. I want to exclude the 2-digit year value.

Comment: Just a note that the CompareValidator is culture dependent, so if you would like another dateformat (e.g. dd-mm-yyyy) just set the culture accordinaly

Comment: This works, but the caveat is that this allows dates that may be out of range of SQL dates less than 1753 or you may have a date range (no future date entries). This does work, but Chris Van Opstal's may be needed for SQL date edits.

Comment: This won't work for the question asked because of the date format specified as "dd MMMM yyyy". CustomValidator on dates only works if the date is in "dd/mm/yyyy" format (for en-GB) or "mm/dd/yyyy" for (en-US).

Answer (score 27):

A CustomValidator would also work here:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
    ID="valDateRange" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted"
    onservervalidate="valDateRange_ServerValidate" 
    ErrorMessage="enter valid date" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void valDateRange_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime minDate = DateTime.Parse("1000/12/28");
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Parse("9999/12/28");
    DateTime dt;

    args.IsValid = (DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out dt) 
                    && dt <= maxDate 
                    && dt >= minDate);
}
```

Comment: I tried your method but it failed within an update panel. Pls chk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071585/asp-net-custom-validation-not-working-even-when-required-field-validator-is-use/14361135#14361135

Comment: This was the best way for me, easiest and i have total control over what is checked&done in the code behind. Thnx alot Chris!!

Comment: This works good for SQL date range edits for legacy systems that use the datetime fields as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I think the following is the easiest way to do it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateControl" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID ="rvDate" runat ="server" ControlToValidate="DateControl" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" Type="Date" MinimumValue="01/01/1900" MaximumValue="01/01/2100" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the dates have to be specified in the current culture of the application.  You might want to experiment with setting [CultureInvariantValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.cultureinvariantvalues.aspx) to true and see if that solves your problem.  Otherwise you may need to change the [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) for the current culture (or the [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) itself) to get what you want.