# Regular expression for date in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, regex

In web application, i am using regular expression for date like "dd-mm-yyyy" format for this i get the validation but it is not working when we enter date like "12-02-2012" remaining condition it is working fine, can you help me this is my validation expression.

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID ="myg" runat ="server" ControlToValidate ="txt" ErrorMessage ="Check"
      ValidationExpression ="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[13456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$" >
  </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I solve the problem,

```
   ValidationExpression ="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[123456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$"
```

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator/939852#939852

Comment: @Shoban: You should have given that as the answer. That has helped me previously. Thanks :)

Comment: I change the expression, now it will work fine for "dd-mm-yyyy" format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slove the problem,

```
 ValidationExpression ="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[13578]|1[02])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|
    ((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[123456789]|1[012])-((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])
    \/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|
    ((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$"
```

Answer (score 2):

`asp:RegularExpression` is not the way to do this.
For validating date using an ASP.NET Validator its *ideal* to use `asp:CompareValidator`

Here is a small mock-up

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDatecompleted" runat="server"/>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="dateValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date."
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    Type="Date"
    ValidationGroup="TestVGroup">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="ClickButton" Text="Click Me" runat="server" 
    ValidationGroup="TestVGroup"
    OnClick="ClickButton_Click" />
```

This will automatically check for different date formats and leap years

Comment: ya sure Naveen i will check and get you back

Comment: ya it is working fine, but i want to restsrict the user not to enter in "01/12/2012" format, user has to enter only "01-12-2012"