# Regular expression for Date and Time validation

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I need regular expression for validating datetime as "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM" where time is in 24hr format.

Can anybody help me solve this.

Thanks for sharing your wisdom.

Comment: Why not [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx) instead of regex?

Comment: I want this expression in RegularExpression validator control of asp.net for validating datetime from textbox.

Comment: @IrfanRaza, i've no experience with asp.net, but i'll be surprised if you can't write a validator that uses DateTime.Parse and return true/false accordingly.

Comment: Using regular expression for that? What about the 31st of February? And all exceptions like that? Use DateTime.Parse!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator. The second answer has a validation function that compares a date to see if it's within a specified range. You could easily modify that to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` for your validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RangeValidator with a given rage of dates or a CustomValidator and then use DateTime.Parse from that