# Validate age restriction in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation

I am new to ASP.NET and I want to set the `RangeValidator` for verifying the date of birth who is above 18. I have set it, but it is not working.

How can I resolve it?

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDOB"
                    ErrorMessage="less than 18 " MaximumValue="01/01/1995" MinimumValue="01/01/1888"
                    SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date" Style="color: #FF0000;"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use an `asp:CustomValidator` with a clientside javascript function.

[Custom Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You could do something like this (note, this is **untested**, just off the top of my head):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="less than 18"
    ClientValidationFunction="checkDate" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDOB">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Assuming the date is written in this format "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
function checkDate() {
   var enteredDate=document.getElementById('<%=txtDOB.ClientID%>').value;
   var dateValues=enteredDate.split("/");
   var dateToCheck = new Date(dateValues[2], dateValues[1]-1, dateValues[0]);
   var today = new Date();
   var dateValid = new Date(today.getFullYear()-18, today.getMonth()-1, today.getDate());
   if (dateToCheck < dateValid) {
     args.IsValid = false;
   }
   else {
     args.IsValid = true;
   }
}
```

**Note**

1. javascript uses 0 for January hence the -1 on the month.
2. You should add a ServerValidation function to the custom validator in case javascript is disabled.

Comment: Regarding point #2, can't he just check `Page.IsValid()` on the server-side?

Comment: @ShaiCohen He'll need custom code on server side too.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Are you sure? It was my understanding that 'Page.Validate()' followed by `Page.IsValid` is the server-side validation of any and all validation server controls. From MSDN: **For this property to return true, all validation server controls in the current validation group must validate successfully. ** Am I missing something?

Comment: @ShaiCohen Yes... because you must specify `OnServerValidate` function for the custom validator.... where else do you think the validation code will come from?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev: Thanks for teaching me something new. I appreciate it.