# Handling datetime type in dropdownlist when trying to add "Select"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get the common "Select" word to appear at index position 0 of a DropDownList box. The DDL is populated SqlDataSource via ASP.

The issue I think is this, the DataSource returns all datatime types from the database which I need because a second DDL appears to allow the selection of an ending date/time greater than the selection made in the first DDL.

The second DDL is also populate in the same manner using the selection results from the first DDL as a condition for all results of 2nd DDL to be greater than.

When I try to insert the "Select" ...

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Select")
```

I get the following error after making a selection in DDL 1, obviously this is not a date/time. But I also did not select the word, I choose a date/time value from the list.

```
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.
```

So is there some way to get ASP to not look at the first position of the list without having to custom code this solution?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this, but as a way round it why not set the `0` value to be a date that cannot be selected otherwise, i.e. set `DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Select")` to be `DropDownList1.Items.Insert("01/01/1900", "Select")`. Then you can check for the `01/01/1900` instead of checking for `0`.

Comment: In many cases "Select" is not actually in the list, but simply the initial value of the text portion.  Unless they are very different in asp, set the DropDownType to DropDown and simply add "Select" to the text portion.  As with the fake "01/01/1900" date you will have to manually check that they selected something in the list because changing to DropDown (vs DropDownList) also allows the user to enter text OR pick.  Either way, you have to validate the selection, but the "01/01/1900" seems a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this, is to manually add an item. You can do this in code behind.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", "01/01/1900"))
```

Please note, that you should add a custom validator to check against this default value.

A valid custom validator is posted in this question:
[Date validation with ASP.NET validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator)

Kind regards

Comment: Isn't the first parameter of `Insert()`, the position?  I don't think that code will compile.

Comment: I honestly can't write vb.net. I just took the OPs code, to make my point with the validator. It may be .Add() for what its worth#

Comment: DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Select", "01/01/1900"))

Comment: Your first answer is also incorrect.  If it's databoud via an sqldatasource, it will override any items in the markup.

Comment: That only leaves the code behind solution to be executed after the databind.

Comment: I hate these cheesy MS work arounds, I wish the control had a property that allowed the first value to be excluded. Or it defaulted to an object when append data bound items is checked. But thank goodness there is one. thanks for all of the replies.