# Server side alert disturbs page styling

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I needed to show a message on web page.  I'm using ASP.Net and C#.  I added below code in the back-end code to show message to the user

```
protected void btnRenew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //other code removed for clarity on where and how this alert is triggered
     if (newExpiryDate.Date == memberDetails.ExpiryDate.Date)
     {
          Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid renewal date');</script>");
     }
}
```

This works fine as expected on the event call.  But, the moment I click `OK` button on the alert message, the font-size of the text increases.  It looks like somehow this alert message is disturbing my styles on the page.

Does anyone know a safe method to display alert from ASP.Net code behind page?

Comment: what browsers? Issue really doesn't make sense

Comment: Blocking script execution is likely actual reason... Trying to come up with [MCVE] may solve the issue.

Comment: @charlietfl, it happens in all browsers I tested - IE, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I know this problem is weird and there is no easy way to be as per your definitions; I know it is even tough to think of a solution with what I provided but even I am not sure how to expand this problem! This is weird for me too; probably if i know how to phrase question, I would know answer :)

Comment: an alert is not part of page itself and is part of window api. I doubt the problem is just the alert and rather as mentioned some other script involved

Comment: @charlietfl - may be true; my client side alerts work fine; it is only problem with the alert I kept on server side; I do have feeling that there must be some standard way of doing server side alerts

Comment: no such thing as server side alert...you are simply sending javscript to run in browser. Is this  full page reload? Or ajax?

Comment: please refer to my updated question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See if

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){alert('Invalid renewal date');},1000);</script>
```

fixes your issue

Using ClientRegisterScriptBlock

```
protected void btnRenew_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //other code removed for clarity on where and how this alert is triggered
     if (newExpiryDate.Date == memberDetails.ExpiryDate.Date)
     {
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
        ("".GetType(), "s", "<script>alert('Invalid renewal date');</script>");
     }
}
```

This renders the script in the HEAD section

Comment: no, it didn't work; i don't think it is an issue with javascript; i think it is the way Response.Write renders this on page

Comment: You used response write to render it?

You should be using RegisterClientScriptBlock.

    string myscript = @"<script language='javascript'>
            alert('hello world');
        </script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock
            ("".GetType(), "s", myscript);
    }


Sorry comments don't format that well.

Comment: Please refer to my code in the question and advise how you would like to do it there

Comment: see above for your code with RegisterClientScriptBlock

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is causing the font shift based on what you posted, but your design can be vastly improved by 1. not making a server call just to validate a date, and 2. not using alert() which locks the whole browser until someone clicks "ok".

You could change your approach to set a few variables in javascript on page load, and then trigger a function on say change of your input or even on button click. your check function could look something like this

```
_memberExpiryDate = new Date('@memberDetails.ExpiryDate.Date'); // or whatever the notation is to write out server variable here

function validate() {
    if (new Date($('#myDateInput').value()) >= _memberExpiryDate.getTime()))
       $('#invalidDateLabel').show();

}
```

this way you're not making unnecessary postbacks, validation can autocorrect as users adjust dates, and there are no alerts in your face.

you can also use a library such as [Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) to show a more graceful message which disappears after a few seconds. but ideally you want to show something right next to the input field like asp.net date validator even

```
toastr.error('date is expired');
```

Also you could just use the [asp.net range Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator).

Comment: i agree; many times implementation depends on certain specific requirements which we end up doing so; i posted it as just an example; I need to lock the browser until someone clicks "ok" :)