# Regex to validate date format MM/DD/YY including leap year

Tags: asp.net, regex, leap-year, validation-controls

I am looking for a regular expression to validate date format mm/dd/yy (including leap year) as well. Date should be masked in MM/DD/YY format. 
Kindly help me find a solution. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Regex can do it. But this is clearly not the tool you want to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression | Leap Years and More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647893/regular-expression-leap-years-and-more)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator

Comment: By the way, this is impossible if you just use mm/dd/**yy** as a date format since `2000` was a leap year and `2100` will not be one.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.TryParse (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). Should do what you want.

Comment: I am looking for date format mm/dd/yy. I see in other post that they have provided solution for mm/dd/yyyy. I am looking for only mm/dd/yy date format.