# ASP.NET Date validation using both Validation and also in .cs file

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am using a piece of code, from which I want to peek the selected date I am using this piece of code

```
<BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="Calendar1" runat="server" placeholder="DD-MM-YY"></BDP:BasicDatePicker>
```

and `RequiredFieldValidator` to check that the field is filled or not.

`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="Calendar1" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must Input a date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Now I want to check if that date is well formatted or valid in format DD-MM-YY(10-Jun-2016)

Comment: You can try to use a `<asp:CompareValidator>` for that. See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/939852/2851870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RegularExpressionValidator  with an expression like:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid date format. Valid dates are dd/mm/yyyy. " ControlToValidate="Calendar1" Display="None" EnableTheming="False" EnableViewState="False" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```